# Error in make.names(fldnms, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 3

Tags: r

I am trying to import a shapefile in R afer importing csv file. Csv file is getting imported successfully.

Links are provided for a similar type of error and they are not much clear. I tried to solve them but  no references are useful.

```
t <- readOGR("/home/user/Desktop/malegaon","malegaon_anganwadi");
```

> Error in make.names(fldnms, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string
>   3

The shape filename is "malegaon_anganwadi" and the folder in which it is saved is /home/user/Desktop/malegaon. The csv file is also saved in the same folder.

Comment: May be check [here](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Error-at-reading-shape-file-readOGR-td5062752.html)

Comment: Thank you. This reference was useful.

Answer (score 2):

I used:

```
x=readOGR("y.shp",use_iconv=TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```